# Singly Linked List using shared_ptr

Tags: c++11, linked-list, shared-ptr

I was trying to implement singly linked list using `share_ptr`. Here is the implementation...
Below is the node class...

```
template<typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    T value;
    shared_ptr<Node<T>> next;
    Node() : value(0), next(nullptr){};
    Node(T value) : value(value), next(nullptr){};
    ~Node() { cout << "In Destructor: " << value << endl; };
};
```

Below is the linked list class...

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    size_t m_size;
    shared_ptr<Node<T>> head;
    shared_ptr<Node<T>> tail;
public:
    LinkedList() : m_size(0), head(nullptr) {};
    void push_front(T value)
    {
        shared_ptr<Node<T>> temp = head;
        head = make_shared<Node<T>>(Node<T>(value));

        head->next = temp;
        m_size++;

        if (m_size == 1)
            tail = head;
    }
    void pop_front()
    {
        if (m_size != 0)
        {
            // Here I am having doubt------------------------!!!
            //shared_ptr<Node<T>> temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            m_size--;
            if (m_size == 0)
                tail = nullptr;
        }
    }
    bool empty()
    {
        return (m_size == 0) ? true : false;
    }
    T front()
    {
        if (m_size != 0)
            return head->value;
    }
};
```

My question is, am I using the `shared_ptr` properly for allocating a node? If not, how should I use the `shared_ptr` to allocate and how should I delete the node in the `pop_front` method?

Comment: Suggested Reading: [This](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33136/singly-linked-list-with-smart-pointers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this belongs on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Most importantly: Why are you using `shared_ptr`? `shared_ptr` means the ownership of an object is unclear. This is not the case for linked lists: Every node owns the next. You can express that using `unique_ptr` which is easier and more efficient.

`pop_front` seems to be functioning correctly. You may consider throwing an exception or an assertion instead of doing nothing when using `pop_front` on an empty list.

`front` is more problematic. If the list is empty you most likely get a garbage object.

What is the significance of `tail`? It does not seem to be used for anything and since you cannot go backwards there is no real point to getting the tail.

`make_shared<Node<T>>(Node<T>(value))` should be `make_shared<Node<T>>(value)` instead. `make_shared<Node<T>>(value)` creates a `Node` using `value` as the parameter for the constructor. `make_shared<Node<T>>(Node<T>(value))` creates a `Node` with `value` as the parameter and then creates a new `Node` with the temporary `Node` as parameter and then destroys the first `Node`.

You are missing the copy and move constructor and assignment and move assignment operators.

After you are satisfied with your list implementation consider using `std::forward_list` instead.